# Trouble installing django-tracking

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, pip

I'm trying to install `django-tracking` but I'm getting a few errors

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',         
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_cleanup.apps.CleanupConfig',
    'tinymce',
    'crispy_forms',
    'tracking',
    'main',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'tracking.middleware.VisitorTrackingMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',  
]
```

`pip install django-tracking`

Output:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'listeners'`

I tried installing `listeners` with no luck

Then I tried `pip install git+https://github.com/bashu/django-tracking.git` but when I run `python manage.py runserver` I get `from django.contrib.gis.geoip import GeoIP, GeoIPException
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.contrib.gis.geoip'`

Comment: Those are compatibility issues. The latest django versions use `GeoIP2` (`from django.contrib.gis.geoip2 import GeoIP2`). django-tracking hasn't been maintained for 5 years, so it'll probably not work with versions of Django higher than 1.8

Answer (score 0):

The django-tracking package hasn't been maintained for more than 5 years, the latest version of Django it supports seems to be 1.5 (and it's built using python 2.7)

So either look for another package doing something similar or fork this and fix it to become compatible with the latest Django version.